# Clojure optional argument to function call

Tags: clojure, arguments

I have a value `a`that may or may not be `nil`.

I have a bunch of functions (outside my control) that should be called with the value of `a` as the first parameter if it is not `nil`. If it is `nil`, the function should be called without `a`.

Instead of:

```
(defn my-fn [x]
  (if a
      (beyond-my-control-fn a x)
      (beyond-my-control-fn x)))
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
(defn my-fn [x]
  (add-argument-if-not-nil-> a (beyond-my-control-fn x)))
```

Is there a macro that allows me to do this already or should I make my own?

Comment: Is `a` a namespace level variable? It is not defined as an argument to your function?

Comment: It is a dynamic top level variable which may or may not be nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mavbozo's answer is correct. I went with a macro due to a personal dislike of simple functions as parameters.

```
(defmacro nn-> [x form]
  (if x
    `(-> ~x ~form)
    `~form))
```

This allows me to use it like so:

```
(nn-> a (beyond-my-control-fn x))

(nn-> a (beyond-my-control-fn x y z))
```

which is, to me, more elegant.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the calling of those beyond-your-control functions with another function

```
(defn call-with-a-if-not-nil
  [f a & args]
  (if (nil? a)
    (apply f args)
    (apply f a args)))
```

samples:

```
(call-with-a-if-not-nil beyond-my-control-fn a x)

(call-with-a-if-not-nil beyond-my-control-fn-1 a v w)
```